# Programmatically update UITextView height

Tags: swift, uitextview

I am trying to update the height of a UITextView based on the content. I have seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46132752/swift-3-uitextview-dynanmic-height-programmatically) but cannot get it to work with my current code (still learning swift)

I define the UITextView as such:

```
    let eventDetailInfoTextBox : UITextView = {
    let textbox = UITextView()
    textbox.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    textbox.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textbox.layer.borderColor = ColorPallet.AppTertiaryColor.cgColor
    textbox.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    textbox.setNeedsDisplay()
    let contentSize = textbox.sizeThatFits(textbox.bounds.size)
    textbox.isEditable = false
    return textbox
}()
```

The subview is then added in setupViews() along with defining its position in the view using a call to setupEventDetailInfoTextBox()

```
    fileprivate func setupEventDetailInfoTextbox() {

    print("Event Detail Info Text Box Height: \(eventDetailInfoTextBox.contentSize.height)")

    var frame = eventDetailInfoTextBox.frame
    frame.size.height = eventDetailInfoTextBox.contentSize.height
    eventDetailInfoTextBox.anchor(eventDetailMapView.bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 8, leftConstant: 10, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 10, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: frame.size.height)

}
```

The call to .anchor is based on the Lets Build That App frameworks found via this [link](https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course_video?id=672) and basically wraps up the local functions from Xcode. I know this works and have reused the same function repeatedly throughout my app.

The output from the print statement is -8 and is represented by a height suitable to show 1 line of text (sometimes).

Can anyone see why my text box refuses to get any bigger if I have more than 1 line of text?

I'm using IOS 10, Xcode 8 and writing in swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these step**

- Create height constraint outlet of TextView.
- Calculate content height of Textview.
- Update TextView height constraint constant value.
- Call layoutIfNeeded() function.

I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks Sushil for your answer. What I forgot to add is I'm not using a storyboard for my layout (hence the .anchor code). Part of my question relates to where I do the tasks you suggest. Can you give any guidance please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something static, down and dirty, you can streamline the process (not set and reset properties) as long as you place everything in the right order. If you need to handle device rotations or other runtime changes, that would require something slightly less down and dirty, but not by much--I'm not sure which you need so I opted for the simpler.

```
// instance property so that other constraints can refer to it
let descriptionTextView = UITextView()

// configure text view
descriptionTextView.text = descriptionModel
descriptionTextView.font = // UIFont
descriptionTextView.textColor = // UIColor
descriptionTextView.isEditable = false
descriptionTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(descriptionTextView)

// set constraints
descriptionTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
descriptionTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: divider.bottomAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
descriptionTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
descriptionTextView.sizeToFit()
descriptionTextView.layoutIfNeeded()
descriptionTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: descriptionTextView.contentSize.height).isActive = true
```